# Delete Last 10 rows from Specific sheets - Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to delete last 10 rows from specific sheets (Sheet1,Sheet2 & Sheet3) of an Excel file. I have tried the below code.

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim Tables As Variant
    Dim rLastRow As Range
    Dim InxW As Long

    Tables = Array("sheet1", "sheet2", "sheet3")

    For InxW = LBound(Tables) To UBound(Tables)
        With Worksheets(Tables(InxW))
            rLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)
            rLastRow.Offset(-9).Resize(10).EntireRow.Delete
        End With
    Next InxW
End Sub
```

The Error I get is on line:

```
rLastRow.Offset(-9).Resize(10).EntireRow.Delete
```

Msg:

> Run-time error '91':
>   Object variable or With block variable not set

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You have a **table** called *Sheet1* ?

Comment: No. It's just a variable to store the sheets name.

Comment: You set a range: `Set rLastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this:

```
With Worksheets(Tables(InxW))

        .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp). _
              Offset(-9).Resize(10).EntireRow.Delete

End With
```

but you should also add a check that there are at least 10 rows you can delete.

Comment: Nice **loop-less** solution !

Comment: But only a loop over `Sheets` not over `Rows`